# How to extend lifetime of member reference?

Tags: c++

Example code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Data {
    int d;
};

class Foo {
    public:
    explicit Foo(const Data& data) : data_(data) {}
    
    void PrintData() {
      std::cout << data_.d << std::endl;
    }
    
    private:
    const Data& data_;
};

Foo CreateFoo(int i) {
    Data d;
    d.d = i;
    return Foo(d);
}

int main() {
    Foo foo = CreateFoo(5);
    foo.PrintData();  // prints 0 instead of 5
    return 0;
}
```

https://ideone.com/KpCstl

`foo.data_` is a reference to the `Data` created in `CreateFoo` which goes out of scope at the end of the function.

**Without changing the definition of `class Foo` (e.g. to remove the reference),** how can I extend the lifetime of `d`/`data_`, preferably so that it matches the lifetime of the `Foo` instance?

Is there perhaps some container object that I can wrap `Foo` in that will keep all its deps alive and return that from `CreateFoo` instead?

---

In the actual usage, our framework will keep `Data` alive, so it will outlive `Foo` as intended. But for my test code, I need to find another mechanism to keep `Data` alive at least until the test run is complete. I can use some kind of singleton to keep it alive, but I'm looking for a cleaner solution.

Comment: Change `Data d;` to `static Data d;` in the `CreateFoo` routine.

Comment: @Eljay Didn't think of that! I think that'll work just fine for my use-case. Thank you!

Comment: The only way I can think of without using static or a more significant change is using coroutines since they retain state. Using static also means that all objects will have exactly the same reference to a single value of Data.

Comment: @M.M Sure, I didn't know if I should write `d` or `data_` there because they both refer to the same object.

Comment: @Eljay But if there are multiple `CreateFoo`s in a row, in the same caller, then every `Foo` object so created will refer to the same `Data`, and so will not necessarily have the Data value that was passed to `CreateFoo`.

Comment: @Anonymous1847 That's a definite downside, so I'll await other answers, but for my test code I think I can live with that restriction. I will only be testing one instance at a time, but there's a risk of bugs creeping in if the object doesn't get properly reset between tests.

Comment: @doug Your suggestion of coroutines might be onto something, you should put that in an answer. Though I wouldn't see the point of using that unless there was some good reason for not having Foos manage their own `Data`s via smart pointers...

Comment: @Anonymous1847 I've adapted your response to @ eljay's idea, and wrote up an answer. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to keep the reference in the member variable, then likely you will need to use dynamic allocation. Think about it -- the reference must point to some Data object somewhere that has the same lifetime as the Foo, but the Data object can't be stored *with* the Foo object, as the Foo object has no space for it, only for a reference. So generally in this case it is allocated on the heap. I would suggest using a unique_ptr to automatically manage this Data object:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

struct Data {
    int d;
};

class Foo {
    public:
    explicit Foo(const Data& data) : data_(std::make_unique<Data>(data)) {}
    
    void PrintData() {
      std::cout << data_->d << std::endl;
    }
    
    private:
    std::unique_ptr<Data> data_;
};

Foo CreateFoo(int i) {
    Data d;
    d.d = i;
    return Foo(d);
}

int main() {
    Foo foo = CreateFoo(5);
    foo.PrintData();
    return 0;
}
```

Note that a `unique_ptr` allows only for one object to have ownership, which will disallow `Foo`s from being copied unless you override the relevant methods. If you want copied `Foo`s to have references to the same object, use `shared_ptr` and `make_shared` instead. If you want copied `Foo`s to copy their `Data` objects, overload the copy constructor and `operator=`, or better yet, turn the `Data` pointer into a plain `Data` member.

If you don't want to have `Foo`s own and manage their `Data`s, then I would suggest:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

struct Data {
    int d;
};

class Foo {
    public:
    explicit Foo(Data& data) : data_(data) {}


    void PrintData() {
      std::cout << data_->d << std::endl;
    }

    private:
    Data& data_;
};

struct FooWithData {
    Data foo_data;
    Foo foo;

    FooWithData(const FooWithData& other)
      : foo_data(other.foo_data),
        foo(foo_data) {}
    
    FooWithData(FooWithData&& other)
      : foo_data(other.foo_data),
        foo(foo_data) {}

    FooWithData& operator=(FooWithData& other) {
        foo_data = other.foo_data;
    }
};

FooWithData CreateFoo(int i) {
    FooWithData ret;
    ret.foo_data = Data { i };
    ret.foo = Foo(ret.foo_data);
    return ret;
}

int main() {
    FooWithData foo_compound = CreateFoo(5);
    foo_compound.foo.PrintData();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There's a couple issues with this. Foremost, the reference is a requirement. It's a well-established pattern we have going. The lifetime of `data_` doesn't need to be tied to `Foo`, it's just `CreateFoo()` I want to modify to keep that local `d` alive long enough. Secondly, I'm not sure this is even functionally similar -- `Data` might be passed into a few different objects, I don't want multiple copies. I guess `shared_ptr` is the obvious workaround, but again, not quite what I was looking for :-)

Comment: @mpen Alrighty, but the reference and the pointer work nearly identically, except for maybe an interchanging of . and -> and the fact there's no smart references really. If you want multiple Foos to refer to the same `Data` object then you would pass pointers into the constructor instead of objects, and use `shared_ptr` or roll your own memory management system, if you're brave enough. Also I think that `d` dies at the end of `CreateFoo`, so I don't think you can extend lifetime in that case, back to the caller of `CreateFoo`.

Comment: Right, a [raw] pointer would have the exact same problem. Which is why I was thinking about changing the return type of `CreateFoo` to something like `FooWithDependencies` and *that* object would manage the lifetimes.

Comment: @M.M. Right, sorry, I was thinking of auto_ptr.

Comment: This suggestion is not much different to just giving Foo a member `Data data;`

Comment: @M.M. Right, but OP asked for the reference semantics to be kept. I also suggested using `shared_ptr` as an alternative.

Comment: @mpen I implemented your suggestion, if you'd like to take a look.

Comment: `FooWithData`  has unexpected behaviour on copy/move construction (the reference will refer to the `Data` in the source object still), so you should write copy and move constructors for `FooWithData`, or at least `delete` them if not wanted. Then the compiler will let you know if you inadvertently request copy/move of the class

Comment: @M.M Yeah my solution at the moment depends on copy elision, as I said. I guess overriding copy/move construction would be a more secure solution.

Comment: @M.M Added overriden copy & move constructors & operator=.

Answer (score 2):

This solution should work for you:

```
Foo CreateFoo(int i) {
    static std::forward_list<Data> v;
    v.push_front(Data{i});
    return Foo(v.front());
}
```

Maintain a `static` container of `Data` objects, add a new object on every call to `CreateFoo`, and hand out references to the last inserted object.

Since the container is `static` you won't have lifetime issues. Also, a container of objects ensures that every call returns a `Foo` that binds to a unique `Data` object.

Also, note that you need a container that doesn't invalidate references to it on modification, so I chose `std::forward_list`.

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/6897nx).

Comment: I'm confused, did I make another mistake then? This is coming out "0" instead of "5" like I expect: https://ideone.com/KpCstl

Comment: @mpen I edited the answer. I think this should do what you want, without modifying `Foo` at all.

Comment: The one downside I can think of for this answer is that every Foo that's created via `CreateFoo` sticks around until the end of the program, which is functionally like a memory leak.

Comment: @Anonymous1847 Absolutely. But OP seems to need this for testing purposes, so essentially one `int` leaking per call to the function is not terrible. I can't think of a simpler way of ensuring that the `Data` objects live as long as the `Foo`s that are returned.

Comment: Probably the cleanest and simplest approach. I'd use a `std::forward_list` Smaller footprint and no need  to be bidirectional.

Comment: In fact, if we're going here, why not just return `Foo(*(new Data{i}))`? Does pretty much the same thing.

Comment: @Anonymous1847 No, I'm not going there actually. That is guaranteed to leak, whereas with the container, OP can extend the implementation potentially to do manual cleanup if it's worth it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your element alive even after scopes ends then you should use pointer, but again raw pointer is dangerous, so to counter this use `std::shared_ptr`, but then you wont be able to use ref variable to `shared_ptr` but an actual `shared_ptr` variable to keep the object of `Data` alive.

```
struct Data{
  int data;
};

class Foo{
public:
  explicit Foo(std:shared_ptr<Data>) {data = _data;}
  Foo createFoo(){
     shared_ptr<Data> d(new Data);
     return Foo(d);//this thing makes sure your shared pointer gets copied and it does not go out of scope
 }
 std::shared_ptr<Data> data;
};
```

Comment: Good idea but you have some syntax errors and other mistakes in the code posted